# Signature error while connecting to s3 bucket via sparklyr

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, sparklyr

I am encountering an error when I  try to connect to a s3 bucket from R studio using sparklyr. The s3 bucket is in the eu-central-1(Frankfurt) region. Spark version - 2.1.0 , Hadoop 2.7. I am getting a 403 response code with signature mismatch error. However,  when I try to get an s3a bucket instead however I get a 400 response code. Any word on alternative methods to connect to s3 buckets via spark in R studio, is also appreciated. The connection to s3 works fine without Spark.

Here is the code,

```
   # install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("rstudio/sparklyr") 
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
spark_disconnect(sc)
config <- spark_config()
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
# config$sparklyr.defaultPackages <- "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3"
# config$spark.executor.memory <- "4g"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local",config = config)


ctx <- sparklyr::spark_context(sc)
jsc <- invoke_static(
sc,
"org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext",
"fromSparkContext",
ctx
)


hconf <- jsc %>% invoke("hadoopConfiguration")
hconf %>% invoke("set","fs.s3.access.key", "xx")
hconf %>% invoke("set","fs.s3.secret.key", "xx")
#hconf %>% invoke("set","com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")
test <- spark_read_csv(sc, "test", "s3://********.csv")
```

```
Error: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Service Error Message. -- ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJ3ZD2ZEISKNQMSGQ</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA25620171129T123633Z20171129/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request555016eca303c98732f51adcaaa83eac7368fb75f59eaa9f59116684b9030ee0</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>bf703f56827aa0f04aab3fa6a1e2aa277117344cdbfc3f4f3e51895ce62af826</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 31 37 31 31 32 39 54 31 32 33 36 33 33 5a 0a 32 30 31 37 31 31 32 39 2f 65 75 2d 63 65 6e 74 72 61 6c 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 35 35 35 30 31 36 65 63 61 33 30 33 63 39 38 37 33 32 66 35 31... <truncated>
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.get(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.Jets3tFileSystemStore.retrieveINode(Jets3tFileSystemStore.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.retrieveINode(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem.getFileStatus(S3FileSystem.java:340)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:381)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$14.apply(DataSource.scala:370)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv(DataFrameReader.scala:352)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sparklyr.Invoke$.invoke(invoke.scala:102)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.handleMethodCall(stream.scala:97)
    at sparklyr.StreamHandler$.read(stream.scala:62)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:52)
    at sparklyr.BackendHandler.channelRead0(handler.scala:14)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:575)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:489)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:451)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:140)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: Service Error Message. -- ResponseCode: 403, ResponseStatus: Forbidden, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAJ3ZD2ZEISKNQMSGQ</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA25620171129T123633Z20171129/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request555016eca303
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to Signature Version incompatibility between regions. There are some regions which do not support Signature Version 2 and you must use Version 4 as mentioned here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html#signature-2-regions-services

When comes to S3 bucket/object access, you must specify the region name (eu-central-1) in your request.

Comment: hconf %>% invoke("set","com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4", "true")

should enforce the v4 signature, right? unfortunately that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

Comment: @Krishnan have you specified the --region <region> switch? Also, see if this package can help you - https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3 ?

Comment: There are also some protocol issues wrt to Hadoop interaction with S3, please take a look at this page for details - https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

Comment: Thanks for writing back, aws.s3 connection works fine, but with difficulties to load really huge data files. The signature problem is only with spark. thanks for the link, will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your AWS credentials via

```
Sys.setenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="[Your access key]")
Sys.setenv(AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="[Your secret access key]")
```

see `?spark_read_csv`

Also `config$sparklyr.defaultPackages <- "org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.3"`
 is essential.

Comment: Yes, I have tried setting the credentials, via Sys.setenv() , also in the hconf %>% invoke("set","fs.s3.access.key", "xx") and also in the spark-defaults.conf file, I can see the values in the environment ,when I run the SparkUI URL.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the bucket via spark-shell using Scala? Might not be a sparklyr specific problem

Comment: Thanks for writing back.

`scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.access.key", "**")
scala> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.secret.key", "**")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.endpoint","s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")
val file = spark.sqlContext.load("s3://****.csv")

ResponseStatus:Forbidden, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Amazon's own EMR then you need to look at their docs.

If you are using Apache's own artifacts, then you need to switch off s3 to the s3a filesystem connector, then enable

1. Set the  JVM system property `com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4` to `true`
2. Set the endpoint `fs.s3a.endpoint` to the endpoint of the specific store you want to talk to [see the list](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/test/resources/core-site.xml#L69).

If things don't work you get a fairly generic "400 bad request" message, which isn't that useful in working out why things are wrong. Start with getting things to work with a bucket in s3 US east (s3a://landsat-pds) is one to try listing, then move to the bucket in the v4 region.